# how to detect root status in android device

Tags: android, root, android-security

I created an app and added root detection. I searched it on internet and discussed it on some forums, but nothing works. Can someone help me about this issue?

I tried these several possibility solutions:

1. [RootBeer](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer)
2. [DetectMagiskHide](https://github.com/darvincisec/DetectMagiskHide)
3. [Boot loader detection](https://github.com/vvb2060/KeyAttestation)
4. [Anti Frida](https://github.com/darvincisec/DetectFrida)

I tested it on this version of Magisks: [Magisk 25.2](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/tag/v25.2), [Magisk Delta](https://huskydg.github.io/magisk-files/)

I hope that anyone able to help me about this issue.
Thank youu and I appreciate it so much for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Even if You found a solution to detect root it may not fully work, **Because Smart modules for bypassing root detecting apps are available** which can break almost any possibility you can think of, including the old techniques you already mentioned.

Even the Phone **Manufacturer's inbuilt root detection apps** (which detect bootloader and hardware techniques too) **can't detect root**. I also use some of the modules

So, my suggestion to you is - Leave the root peoples in their zone and **focus on making your app more secure and foolproof**. Why to increase your line of codes, which is of no use.??